# Different activities for different device's type

Tags: android, wear-os, intentfilter

I have an application for smartphones. In my `AndroidManifest.xml` file placed activity with special `intent-filter`

```
    <activity
        android:name=".feature.splashscreen.SplashScreenVm"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now, I need to launch my application on wearable devices. Obviously, default activity for wearable device should be `WearableActivity.class`. How to configure my `AndroidManifest.xml` to launch different activities depending on device's type? Or maybe it should be handled not by manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, for wearable devices(e.g watches), you need to have a different apk.
It currently is not possible to create a single APK that works on a phone and watch.
for more info you can check : 
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html

EDIT:

I also found a tutorial about how to do what you plan;
https://medium.com/@manuelvicnt/android-wear-add-a-wear-app-to-your-already-existing-android-app-2a668442dd0a

Answer (score 0):

It is true the apks are different. I would advise if you to build a second app for wearables with limited functionality or only the important functions that are in your smartphone app. Take note wearable devices have limited screen real estate so you might want to just use it for something such as just notifications.